# jQuery Promise then not working after AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I have my Promise defined as so:

```
myFunc = function() {
    $.getJSON("./rest/api/some/url", function(json, textStatus) {
        console.log("AJAX call hit!");
    });
};


$.when(myFunc()).then(function() {
  console.log("Then block hit!");
});
```

and in console it's being output as:

```
Then block hit!
AJAX call hit!
```

I need the `AJAX call hit!` first followed by the `Then block hit!`.

Any idea why this is happening? I even tried to implement a custom callback function (a standard example I found on Stackoverflow) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$.when` on function calls that return promises. Then you'd quickly have found out that your function doesn't return a promise :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this question needs a more complete explanation.

`$.when()` has no magical powers to know when some function you put inside its parens happens to be done.  It only works with async operations when you pass `$.when()` one or more promises that are themselves resolved when the underlying async operation is done.

So, in your code:

```
myFunc = function() {
    $.getJSON("./rest/api/some/url", function(json, textStatus) {
        console.log("AJAX call hit!");
    });
};

$.when(myFunc()).then(function() {
    console.log("Then block hit!");
});
```

`myFunc()` is returning nothing which means `undefined`, so you're in essence doing:

```
myFunc();
$.when(undefined).then(function() {
    console.log("Then block hit!");
});
```

When you don't pass any promises to `$.when()`, it just resolves immediately (since it has nothing to wait for).

Instead, you need to make sure that `myFunc()` returns a promise that is resolved when the Ajax call is done.  Since jQuery's `$.getJSON()` already returns such a promise, all you have to do is to return that promise like this:

```
var myFunc = function() {
    return $.getJSON("./rest/api/some/url", function(json, textStatus) {
        console.log("AJAX call hit!");
    });
};

$.when(myFunc()).then(function() {
     console.log("Then block hit!");
});
```

---

Of course, when there's only one promise to wait on, there is no reason to use `$.when()` at all as it is just extra code getting in the way.  `$.when()` really only adds value when you have more than one promise you want to wait on.  So, instead you can just do this:

```
var myFunc = function() {
    return $.getJSON("./rest/api/some/url", function(json, textStatus) {
        console.log("AJAX call hit!");
    });
};

myFunc().then(function() {
     console.log("Then block hit!");
});
```

Comment: Added a better method that doesn't even use `$.when()` since it is not needed when there is only one promise.

Comment: +1 for asserting that there is no magic in promises                                                                           :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need promise-compatible object functon `myFunc()` returns null

```
$.when(null).then(function() {
    console.log("Then block hit!");
});
```

output : Then block hit!

Try

```
return $.getJSON("...
```