# jQuery promise (when > then) not working with iterating through array with $.each and $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, asynchronous

I've been searching and trying so many variations, with no luck.

I have an array of users:

```
var arr = ['tom', 'sally', 'jill', 'sam', 'john'];
```

I am wanting to pass these users into 2 APIs (same site, different URLs, for different data sets) with $.ajax:

```
function getStatus1() {
  return $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
    arrStatus.push($.ajax({
        url: 'https://some/url',
        dataType: 'json'
      })
      .always(function (response) {
        console.log('from getStatus1');
      }));
  });
}

function getStatus2() {
  return $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
    arrStatus.push($.ajax({
        url: 'https://some/url',
        dataType: 'json'
      })
      .always(function (response) {
        console.log('from getStatus2');
      }));
  });
}

$.when(getStatus1(), getStatus2()).then(function () {
  console.log('after getStatuses');
});
```

No matter what I try, I'm always getting 'after getStatuses' first, which I gather is because I'm not returning promises in my functions... but I don't know why this is the case!!

This article was the closest I got to my situation, but it doesn't deal with using $.each or arrays... :(
[jQuery Promise then not working after AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212391/jquery-promise-then-not-working-after-ajax)

I would really appreciate any help / light that anyone can shed on my problem.

Thank you!

**edit**
Here's a Plnkr to demonstrate my ajax woes:
https://plnkr.co/edit/jRAAjXX4zFprUbx1KPlN?p=preview

Thanks for all the replies, and I really hope there's a solution!

Comment: What about to try to push to the array inside the success ajax response callback?

Comment: your when... then is working but ithink issue in your ajax call

Comment: I've tried that too:

    function getDetails() {
  return $.each(arr, function (index, value) {
    arrDetails.push($.ajax({
      url: 'https://some/url/' + value,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (response) {
        console.log('from getDetails');
      }
    }));
  });
}

... gives the same result :(

Comment: `$.each` doesn't return a value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.each` doesn't return a value, so there's no point returning one.

Instead of using `$.each`, use `Array.prototype.map` (there's no equivalent in jQuery) and `return` the promise inside the callback, e.g.

```
function getStatus1() {
  return arr.map(function(value, index) {
      return $.ajax({
          url: 'https://some/url',
          dataType: 'json'
      });
  });
}
```

However, note that you've now (once you've fixed both functions) got *two* arrays of promises.  `$.when()` won't handle the nesting, unless you do:

```
$.when($.when.apply($, getStatus1()), $.when.apply($, getStatus2()).then(...)
```

Alternatively arrange for the two functions to return a single promise from their arrays:

```
function getStatus1() {
    return $.when.apply($, arr.map(...))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply! I spent a lot of time using this to try to get my code to work... without success. I ended up creating a Plnkr 
https://plnkr.co/edit/jRAAjXX4zFprUbx1KPlN?p=preview
to demonstrate my ajax woes...

The main problem seems to be the array – if the array produces no 'fails' in the ajax call, then the 'when' will output... but if the array produces a 'fail', then the 'when' doesn't output.

I feel like I'm learning a lot, but also getting somewhere!

Comment: @dm400 if it solved your problem the usual practise here is to "accept' the answer :)

Comment: thanks – I'm still not able to get the 'when' output to display after the 'getStatus' output – when the array generates a 'fail'... I ended up having to manipulate the array inside the 'always' method. 
Anyway, yep – answer accepted now – thanks for your help.

Comment: @dm4000 that's the document behavior of `$.when` - if one fails, the `$.when` promise does too.

Comment: ah! that helps – makes a lot of sense why the code behaved the way it did. thanks!